# Tooltip on multiple values within single textbox in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, tooltip

I have a textbox 'Department Code' in which i get values separated by delimiter '*'. I need to put the values in new line within the textbox and apply tooltip on each value in the single textbox itself , i tried with multilookup function but it didn't work. 
Kindly help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gczc8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two place holders as you have shown in your image description (right click on the text box and select Placeholder Properties) and then set the tooltip to whatever you want.

[[image: Place Holder Property[1]]

You can have multiple placeholders in a single text box and you can also use html commands to make your fields appears as fancy as you want, just ensure you select HTML as markup Style

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the answer, it gave me a starting point to implement my functionality, but I am facing issue with placeholder when the value is null, so can you please help me how to hide placeholder when the value is null,i checked that there is no property as 'visibility' within placeholder. Kindly suggest.

Comment: the placeholder should not display anything if the value is null. . Are you able to share what is being displayed? You could check for nulls and display if value is available or a blank.. something like = iff(isnothing(fields!yourcolumn.value),"") or something to that effect